# unrecognized selector sent to instance , UISlider swfit3

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, unrecognized-selector

I'm working with UISlider and I want recognize a change of value:

```
var sliderGeofence: UISlider!
```

Inside my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
 self.sliderGeofence = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 50, height: 50))
        self.sliderGeofence?.maximumValue = 100000
        self.sliderGeofence?.minimumValue = 500
        self.sliderGeofence?.value = 100
        self.sliderGeofence?.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
        self.sliderGeofence?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("geofenceValueChange:"),for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        gmsMap.addSubview(self.sliderGeofence!)
        sliderGeofence?.isHidden = true
```

My value-change method:

```
 @IBAction func geofenceValueChange(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    print("entro")
    }
```

The app loads the slider, however, when I change its value this happens:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MocaAdmin.FirstViewController
>   geofenceValueChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fca61511480'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try changing add target to : `self.sliderGeofence?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(geofenceValueChange:), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)`

Comment: @Priyal, you're part-way there. See Rashwan's answer, below. The Swift form of the selector will be `geofenceValueChange(_:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the target to the following:

```
sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(geofenceValueChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

And then the function to:

```
func geofenceValueChange(_ sender:UISlider) {
    print("entro")
}
```

No need for the `@IBAction` in the function.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the selector like this:

```
self.sliderGeofence?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.geofenceValueChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

That way, Xcode will even suggest functions to use and autocomplete your typing to ensure things will work.

Hope that helps!